# In Dominion, when it says reveal a card, who must I reveal it to?

Tags: dominion

The text of [Bureaucrat](http://dominioncg.wikia.com/wiki/Bureaucrat) reads:

> Gain a Silver card, put it on top of your deck. Each other player reveals a Victory card and puts it on top of his deck. (or reveals a hand with no Victory cards).

When I play the card and a player does not have any victory cards in their hand, it instructs you to reveal a hand with none. Should they only reveal their hand to me or are they required to reveal their hand to the entire group of players?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Reveal** means to show their hand to the table.

From the [rules](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_278_gameRules.pdf), page 7.

> **Reveal** – when a player reveals a card, he shows a card to all players and
>   then returns it to wherever it came from (unless instructed specifically to
>   put it elsewhere). If the player is required to reveal cards from the top of
>   his Deck, and he does not have enough cards, he shuffles in order to
>   reveal the required number of cards.